# fail to geting xml data with $_SESSION condition

Tags: php, xml

i am trying to get xml data from my website. with this code

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.mywebsite.com/dataxml.php');
foreach ($xml->id as $id) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$id->phone."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$id->first_name." ".$id->last_name."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$id->update."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
```

it work fine with below code in website file dataxml.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
include_once('customer.php');
$ThisCustomer = new Customer_Info;
echo $ThisCustomer->xmlCustomers();
```

but when i am trying to get with below code i get error.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['authorize'])) return;   
// if i place this line before/after header result is same
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
include_once('customer.php');
$ThisCustomer = new Customer_Info;
echo $ThisCustomer->xmlCustomers();
```

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://www.mywebsite.com/dataxml.php:1: parser error : Document is empty in C:\wamp\www\xml_show.php on line 29

also note:
if i visit direct site with 2nd code like http://www.mywebsite.com/dataxml.php it does display xml data correctly.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` somewhere in your application flow before the use of `$_SESSION['authorize']`?

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['authorize']` actually set? If not, loading the dataxml.php file will return an empty page which is what your error says is happening.

Comment: @BadWolf yes $_SESSION['authorize'] is set. as i mentioned if i visit direct link its work fine.